# Import errors between some python moduls/functions/variables

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror, pylint

This code worked on Friday without problems and still running on a colleagues laptop, but I cannot run it anymore.
As you can see in the screenshot, my editor doesnt find some moduls anymore and the pylint Error "E0401: Unable to import" occurs. 
The missing file exists in the folder Settings, as you can see in the Explorer on the left side.

Today I deactivated/activated pylint, reinstalled vs code and python, added the **init**.py to Settings folder, tried the same code in eclipse, modified the Path enviroment variable and created the PYTHONPATH enviroment variable. All this with no success:/

I am greatful for each hint, which provide me to solve this problem.

[image]

The error output as text:

```
    Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

PS C:\Users\Evgenij\Desktop\Desktop\Eth_Test_Dev> & C:/Python27/python.exe c:\Users\Evgenij\Desktop\Desktop\Eth_Test_Dev\Code\__TC__Template.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Evgenij\Desktop\Desktop\Eth_Test_Dev\Code\__TC__Template.py", line 36, in <module>
    from Lib.IHR_EthApi import EthApi as ETH
  File "c:\Users\Evgenij\Desktop\Desktop\Eth_Test_Dev\Code\Lib\IHR_EthApi.py", line 6, in <module>
    from IHR_GeneralApi import GeneralApi as SYS
  File "c:\Users\Evgenij\Desktop\Desktop\Eth_Test_Dev\Code\Lib\IHR_GeneralApi.py", line 4, in <module>
    import IHR_TestSuiteConfig.py
ImportError: No module named IHR_TestSuiteConfig.py
PS C:\Users\Evgenij\Desktop\Desktop\Eth_Test_Dev>
```

Comment: Please use text for your question and error output rather than a screenshot.  Images are not searchable so are unlikely to be useful for any future reference

Comment: Thx for the hint.  I added some more information and the error output. Tell me when you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have the line:

```
import IHR_TestSuiteConfig.py
```

That won't work because you don't specify modules to import by file name but by module name, e.g.:

```
import IHR_TestSuiteConfig
```

But looking at your screenshot you have a bigger issue of the code being kept in a `Settings` directory at the same level as your `Lib` directory containing the code you are importing into.

You need to either anchor all of your code up a level so you can do:

```
from ..Settings import IHR_TestSuiteConfig
```

Or you need to manipulate your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to put `Settings` directly on to `sys.path` (in VS Code you can create a `.env` file to do this, but it won't' affect running Python from the terminal, only when VS Code runs e.g. Pylint).

Comment: Thaks for you Answer! 
There was really a bigger issue, but i think it was solved as i added the Settings folder to Path and PYTHONPATH as you said.
Now i working on the next problem, but that will be another topic.